# Is x >= 0 more efficient than x > -1?

Tags: c++, optimization, micro-optimization

Doing a comparison in C++ with an int is `x >= 0` more efficient than `x > -1`?

Comment: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil."

Comment: At this point, does it really matter? Which is more logical and understandable given your context?

Comment: Try that on unsigned :P

Comment: I dont' want to optimize any code is just for fun

Comment: In c++ without any information about the platform and compiler used that question can't really be answered. For most platforms/compilers the answer is a) there won't be a difference for the comparison and b) if there is the compiler might transform one into the other anyways

Comment: I disagree with the "not constructive" votes. While it's true that the answer is "you can't know", it doesn't mean there is no answer, and that the answer won't be helpful.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

short answer: no.

longer answer to provide some educational insight: it depends entirely on your compiler, allthough i bet that every sane compiler creates identical code for the 2 expressions.

example code:

```
int func_ge0(int a) {
    return a >= 0;
}   

int func_gtm1(int a) {
    return a > -1; 
}
```

and then compile and compare the resulting assembler code:

```
   % gcc -S -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer foo.cc
```

yields this:

```
_Z8func_ge0i:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    .cfi_personality 0x0,__gxx_personality_v0
    movl    4(%esp), %eax
    notl    %eax
    shrl    $31, %eax
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

vs.

```
_Z9func_gtm1i:
.LFB1:
    .cfi_startproc
    .cfi_personality 0x0,__gxx_personality_v0
    movl    4(%esp), %eax
    notl    %eax
    shrl    $31, %eax
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

(compiler: g++-4.4)

conclusion: don't try to outsmart the compiler, concentrate on algorithms and data structures, benchmark and profile real bottlenecks, if in doubt: check the output of the compiler.

Comment: This particular assembly is actually pretty clever: It returns the value of the most-significant bit, i.e. the "sign bit".

Comment: i've seen similar smart stuff for eg `fabs(1.0)` vs `1.0 < 0.0 ? 1.0 :  -1.0`.

Answer (score 7):

You can look at the resulting assembly code, which may differ from architecture to architecture, but I would bet that the resulting code for either would require exactly the same cycles.

And, as mentioned in the comments - better write what's most comprehensible, optimize when you have real measured bottlenecks, which you can identify with a profiler.

BTW: Rightly mentioned, that `x>-1` may cause problems if `x` is `unsigned`. It may be implicitly cast into `signed` (although you should get a warning on that), which would yield incorrect result.

Answer (score 6):

Remember: measure. And don't optimize prematurely!

There is no alternative to measuring.

You need to keep in mind that what you're measuring is just that: that a single set of measurements does not necessarily tell you anything in general, but just a specific result. Of course it might sound patronizing to mention such obvious things. So, OK, let that be it: just measure.

Or, should I perhaps mention that most processors have a special instruction for comparing against zero, and yet that that does not allow one to conclude anything about performance of your code snippets?

---

---

**EDIT**: *an amendment with the points mentioned by @MooingDuck in the commentary*.

#### The question:

> Doing a comparison in C++ with an `int` is `x >= 0` more efficient than `x > -1`?

#### What’s wrong with the question

Donald Knuth, author of the classic three volume work The Art of Computer Programming, once wrote[1],

> *“We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil”*

How *efficient* `x >= 0` is compared to `x > -1` is most often irrelevant. I.e. it’s most likely a wrong thing to focus on.

How *clearly* it expresses what you want to say, is much more important. Your time and the time of others maintaining this code is generally much more important than the execution time of the program. Focus on how well the code communicates to other programmers, i.e., focus on clarity.

#### Why the focus of the question is wrong

Clarity affects the chance of correctness. Any code can be made arbitrarily fast if it does not need to be correct. Correctness is therefore most important, and means that clarity is very important – much more important than shaving a nano-second of execution time…

And the two expressions are *not* equivalent wrt. clarity, and wrt. to their chance of being correct.

If `x` is a signed integer, then `x >= 0` means exactly the same as `x > -1`. But if `x` is an unsigned integer, e.g. of type `unsigned`, then `x > -1` means `x > static_cast<unsigned>(-1)` (via **implicit promotion**), which in turn means `x > std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::max()`. Which is presumably not what the programmer meant to express!

Another reason why the focus is wrong (it’s on micro-efficiency, while it should be on clarity) is that the main impact on efficiency comes in general not from timings of individual operations (except in some cases from dynamic allocation and from the even slower disk and network operations), but from **algorithmic efficiency**. For example, writing …

```
string s = "";
for( int i = 0;  i < n;  ++i ) { s = s + "-"; }
```

is pretty inefficient, because it uses time proportional to the square of *n*, O(*n*<sup>2</sup>), **quadratic time**.

But writing instead …

```
string s = "";
for( int i = 0;  i < n;  ++i ) { s += "-"; }
```

reduces the time to proportional to *n*, O(*n*), **linear time**.

With the focus on individual operation timings one could be thinking now about writing `'-'` instead of `"-"`, and such silly details. Instead, with the focus on clarity, one would be focusing on making that code more clear than with a loop. E.g. by using the appropriate `string` constructor:

```
string s( n, '-' );
```

Wow!

Finally, a third reason to not sweat the small stuff is that in general it’s just a very small part of the code that contributes disproportionally to the execution time. And identifying that part (or parts) is not easy to do by just analyzing the code. Measurements are needed, and this kind of "where is it spending its time" measurement is called **profiling**.

#### How to figure out the answer to the question

Twenty or thirty years ago one could get a reasonable idea of efficiency of individual operations, by simply looking at the generated machine code.

For example, you can look at the machine code by running the program in a debugger, or you use the approiate option to ask the compiler to generate an assembly language listing. Note for g++: the option `-masm=intel` is handy for telling the compiler not to generate ungrokkable AT&T syntax assembly, but instead Intel syntax assembly. E.g., Microsoft's assembler uses extended Intel syntax.

Today the computer's processor is more smart. It can execute instructions out of order and even before their effect is needed for the "current" point of execution. The compiler may be able to predict that (by incorporating effective knowledge gleaned from measurements), but a human has little chance.

The only recourse for the ordinary programmer is therefore to **measure**.

Measure, measure, measure!

And in general this involves doing the thing to be measured, a zillion times, and dividing by a zillion.

Otherwise the startup time and take-down time will dominate, and the result will be garbage.

Of course, if the generated machine code is the same, then measuring will not tell you anything useful about the relative difference. It can then only indicate something about how large the measurement error is. Because you know then that there should be zero difference.

#### Why measuring is the right approach

Let’s say that theoretical considerations in an SO answer indicated that `x >= -1` will be slower than `x > 0`.

The compiler can beat any such theoretical consideration by generating awful code for that `x > 0`, perhaps due to a contextual "optimization" opportunity that it then (unfortunately!) recognizes.

The computer's processor can likewise make a mess out of the prediction.

So in any case you then have to measure.

Which means that the theoretical consideration has told you nothing useful: you’ll be doing the same anyway, namely, measuring.

References:

[1] Knuth, Donald. [Structured Programming with go to Statements](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.103.6084&rep=rep1&type=pdf), ACM Journal Computing Surveys, Vol 6, No. 4, Dec. 1974. p.268.

Comment: Unfortunately, just because an answer is accurate doesn't mean it is a good answer.

Comment: @Mooing Duck: i'm addressing people who do think a correct and complete answer is a good answer. i am aware though that this does not always fit SO, which is more of a social site than technical. for example, one can't have a technical site that actively discourages discussion, but that's what SO does, and one can't have a technical site where information (including history) is arbitrarily altered by moderators, but that's how it is on SO, so, it is correct I think that "good" can mean something different here.

Comment: True: "good" is unclear.  I think "helpful" might have fit my statement better.

Comment: @MooingDuck: in that case I don't understand what you're trying to express. My original single word answer to a similar question was most helpful, because it was complete and accurate and minimal. If you look at "the solution" for this question, it goes on and on (babble babble) with examples of how nothing can be said a priori, then just vaguely indicates the measuring is the only way. That's not a good answer. So, again, I don't understand your point, but is it, that to be a "helpful" answer the answer should not say right out what to do, but rather beat around the bush -- is that it?

Comment: A helpful answer: shows what's wrong, explains why it's wrong, shows how to do it right, explains why it's right.  In this case: how to profile.

Comment: @Mooing Duck: well I can amend my answer here to do that (no other answer does that yet), but I'm not sure that I agree that that's more helpful. it's like, if you ask how to open a door, then simply being directed to the electronic door-open button, "there!", can be much more helpful than a long discussion of why trying the manual handle doesn't work, how to push the electronic button, and why that is the right thing to do to open the door. i personally prefer the short and to the point "there!"; i can figure the rest myself...

Comment: When reviewing other's answers, I focus a lot on the FAQ part and imagine that we're trying to teach English majors.  When I write my own answers though, I usually forget to do that, and focus on the one person I'm helping, and adjust my answer to their apparent competency level. (Leading to "there!" as well).  Usually comments remind me to go back and clarify what I did though.  I admit some problems are so simple that "there!" is really all the answer there is.

Comment: I'm a bit conflicted, on one side I want to +1 because its a very well written answer and explanation. On the other hand - I'm not sure its helpful to the OP. I mean, yeah, you answered the question, but I wonder whether the OP has actually read it at all and understood what you're saying? I doubt so...

Answer (score 3):

Your compiler is free to decide how to implement those (which assembly instructions to use). Because of that, there is no difference. One compiler could implement `x > -1` as `x >= 0` and another could implement `x >= 0` as `x > -1`. If there is any difference (unlikely), your compiler will pick the better one.

Answer (score 2):

They should be equivalent.  Both will be translated by the compiler into a single assembly instruction (neglecting that both will need to load x into a register).  On any modern day processor there is a 'greater-than' instruction and a 'greater-than-or-equal' instruction.  And since you are comparing it to a constant value, it will take the same amount of time.

Don't fret over the minute details, find the big performance problems (like algorithm design) and attack those, look at Amdahls Law.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there is any measurable difference.  The compiler should emit some assembled code with [a jump instruction](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/x86-jumps.html) such as `JAE` (jump if above or equal) or `JA` (jump if above).  These instructions likely span the same number of cycles.

Ultimately, it doesn't matter.  Just use what is more clear to a human reader of your code.