# is i=(i+1)&3 faster than i=(i+1)%4

Tags: c++, micro-optimization

I am optimizing a c++ code. 
at one critical step, I want to implement the following function `y=f(x)`:

```
f(0)=1

f(1)=2

f(2)=3

f(3)=0
```

which one is faster ? using a lookup table or  `i=(i+1)&3`  or  `i=(i+1)%4` ? or any better suggestion?

Comment: Why don't you try both and measure? Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8316332/is-x-0-more-efficient-than-x-1/8316403#8316403

Comment: The best way to find out is measure. Checking the generated code will probably tell you that they are equal. If you *really* want to indulge in micro-optimisations: avoid the function and make it a macro or an inlined function.

Comment: Thanks everyone. All the comments were right and quite useful.

Comment: to answer those who asked why I didn't just tried both: I hoped someone may come with an out of the box solution to this, that I hadn't thought of. thanks anyways.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Almost certainly the lookup table is going to be slowest.  In a lot of cases, the compiler will generate the same assembly for `(i+1)&3` and `(i+1)%4`; however depending on the type/signedness of i, they may not be strictly equivalent and the compiler won't be able to make that optimization.  For example for the code

```
int foo(int i)
{
    return (i+1)%4;
}

unsigned bar(unsigned i)
{
    return (i+1)%4;
}
```

on my system, `gcc -O2` generates:

```
0000000000000000 <foo>:
   0:   8d 47 01                lea    0x1(%rdi),%eax
   3:   89 c2                   mov    %eax,%edx
   5:   c1 fa 1f                sar    $0x1f,%edx
   8:   c1 ea 1e                shr    $0x1e,%edx
   b:   01 d0                   add    %edx,%eax
   d:   83 e0 03                and    $0x3,%eax
  10:   29 d0                   sub    %edx,%eax
  12:   c3                      retq   

0000000000000020 <bar>:
  20:   8d 47 01                lea    0x1(%rdi),%eax
  23:   83 e0 03                and    $0x3,%eax
  26:   c3                      retq
```

so as you can see because of the rules about signed modulus results, `(i+1)%4` generates a lot more code in the first place.

Bottom line, you're probably best off using the `(i+1)&3` version if that expresses what you want, because there's less chance for the compiler to do something you don't expect.

Answer (score 7):

I won't get into the discussion of premature optimization. But the answer is that they will be the same speed.

Any sane compiler will compile them to the same thing. Division/modulus by a power of two will be optimized to bitwise operations anyway.

**So use whichever you find (or others will find) to be more readable.**

EDIT : As Roland has pointed out, it does sometimes behave different depending on the signness:

**Unsigned &:**

```
int main(void)
{
    unsigned x;
    cin >> x;
    x = (x + 1) & 3;
    cout << x;

    return 0;
}

mov eax, DWORD PTR _x$[ebp]
inc eax
and eax, 3
push    eax
```

**Unsigned Modulus:**

```
int main(void)
{
    unsigned x;
    cin >> x;
    x = (x + 1) % 4;
    cout << x;

    return 0;
}

mov eax, DWORD PTR _x$[ebp]
inc eax
and eax, 3
push    eax
```

**Signed &:**

```
int main(void)
{
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    x = (x + 1) & 3;
    cout << x;

    return 0;
}

mov eax, DWORD PTR _x$[ebp]
inc eax
and eax, 3
push    eax
```

**Signed Modulus:**

```
int main(void)
{
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    x = (x + 1) % 4;
    cout << x;

    return 0;
}

mov eax, DWORD PTR _x$[ebp]
inc eax
and eax, -2147483645            ; 80000003H
jns SHORT $LN3@main
dec eax
or  eax, -4                 ; fffffffcH
```

Comment: I don't think any compiler is smart enough to turn the lookup table into the same code as modulus/and.  And see my answer for why the `%` and the `&` versions might generate different code.

Comment: I forgot to mention the lookup table, but yes, the compiler will not likely to be able to optimize it.

Answer (score 5):

Good chances are, you wouldn't find any differences: any reasonably modern compiler knows to optimize both into the same code.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried benchmarking it? As an offhand gues, I'll assume that the `&3` version will be faster, as that's a simple addition and bitwise AND operation, both of which should be single-cycle operations on any modern-ish CPU.

The `%4` could go a few different ways, depending on how smart the compiler is. it could be done via division, which is much slower than addition, or it could be translated into a bitwise `and` operation as well and end up being just as fast as the `&3` version.

Answer (score 0):

same as Mystical but C and ARM

```
int fun1 ( int i )
{
    return( (i+1)&3 );
}

int fun2 ( int i )
{
    return( (i+1)%4 );
}

unsigned int fun3 ( unsigned int i )
{
    return( (i+1)&3 );
}

unsigned int fun4 ( unsigned int i )
{
    return( (i+1)%4 );
}
```

creates:

```
00000000 <fun1>:
   0:   e2800001    add r0, r0, #1
   4:   e2000003    and r0, r0, #3
   8:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

0000000c <fun2>:
   c:   e2802001    add r2, r0, #1
  10:   e1a0cfc2    asr ip, r2, #31
  14:   e1a03f2c    lsr r3, ip, #30
  18:   e0821003    add r1, r2, r3
  1c:   e2010003    and r0, r1, #3
  20:   e0630000    rsb r0, r3, r0
  24:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

00000028 <fun3>:
  28:   e2800001    add r0, r0, #1
  2c:   e2000003    and r0, r0, #3
  30:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

00000034 <fun4>:
  34:   e2800001    add r0, r0, #1
  38:   e2000003    and r0, r0, #3
      3c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

For negative numbers the mask and the modulo are not equivalent, only for positive/unsigned numbers.  For those cases your compiler should know that %4 is the same as &3 and use the less expensive on (&3) as gcc above. clang/llc below

```
fun3:                             
    add r0, r0, #1
    and r0, r0, #3
    mov pc, lr

fun4:
    add r0, r0, #1
    and r0, r0, #3
    mov pc, lr
```

Answer (score -1):

Ofcourse & is faster then %. Which is proven by many previous posts. Also as i is local variable, u can use ++i instead of i+1, as it is better implemented by most of the compilers. i+1 may(not) be optimized as ++i.

UPDATE: Perhaps i was not clear, i meant, the function should just "return((++i)&3);"

Comment: -1, `i=(++i)&3` is in fact invalid (two writes, neither of which is sequenced-before the other).

Comment: I think you interpreted wrong... I was trying to tell return((++i)&3)).